# Does JIRA have a method to call JQuery(window).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira, jira-rest-api

We have a Jura plugin written by ourselves, and in it's vm template at the very end there's the following code:

```
AJS.$(window).ready(function(){
    doSomeThing();
});
```

Inside of this method we are loading some server side data and initializing internal js objects. For some strange reason this specific method doSomeThing is being called twice. Moreover, vm template is also being called twice, owerwriting first template initialization state (but template may be already initialized and contain some data at this point). I don't get it why it's made this way and how to work around this. If someone faced similar thing before and knows what to deal with it - please respond. Much appreciated.

Comment: We've found a reason of such bahavior - it's Backbone. Jira creates an element using Backbone View, which calls AJS.$().ready second time during initialization. We stopped usage of this element after our investigation.

Comment: Why don't you post your answer as an answer to your own question and select it as the solving answer? This might help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found a reason of such bahavior - it's Backbone. Jira creates an element using Backbone View, which calls AJS.$().ready second time during initialization. We stopped usage of this element after our investigation